# fetching local file on Ionic iOS Capacitor project gives cross Origin error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, fetch, capacitor

Here's a snippet of my code. I'm trying to use a trick I learned which makes use of fetch to convert a file path to a blob. **This works fine on my desktop Chrome and on Android**, but produces an error on iOS.

```js
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { VideoEditor } from '@ionic-native/video-editor/ngx';

// irrelevant code here...

return this.videoEditor
  .transcodeVideo(transcodeOptions)
  .then((path) => {
    fullPathTranscoded = "file://" + path
    // I've verified that the error comes from here
    return fetch(Capacitor.convertFileSrc(fullPathTranscoded))
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res.blob()
  })
  .then(async (blob) => {
    videoInfo = await this.getVideoInfo(fullPathTranscoded)
    return blob
  })
```

The error is `Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

I'm working with Ionic/Angular and building with Capacitor.

There are some similar questions online but I haven't found one that's totally relevant to my setup.

Comment: Why not use [Filesystem](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem/#type-434)?

Comment: @Eldar I noticed that readFile returns a string, so I'd have to then convert it to a blob/file for my purposes. It felt beautifully simple to use the one liner with fetch, and I remember going around in circles trying other methods provided by Filesystem. If you've got a specific solution though, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: As `readFile` returns base64 encoded data you can combine your solution with `readFile`. Like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183085/12354911).

Comment: Okay! Will give it a try and get back if there are further issues

Comment: @Eldar It worked okay. I had issues on Android, so being in a rush I just checked which platform and used the method that works. Thanks!